# Why does Hibernate sorts my list that way?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting

I want to sort a list using Hibernate's [Criterias](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), but don't understand how the framework sorts the results. I have a list of strings to query and sort. The values are as follow:

- MCGuffin Super
- MCGuffin Mega
- McGuffin powerup
- MCGuffin 1
- MCGuffin Super
- MCGuffin 2
- MCGuffin Mega

I want to sort them in ascending order. I expect this result: `1, 2, Mega, Mega, powerup, Super, Super`.

However, I end up with: `Mega, Mega, powerup, Super, Super, 1, 2`.

I first thought it was because the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), however uppercase and lowercases are treated at the same level (despite lowercases having a higher ASCII address).

---

The only thing I saw in my code that could potentially be relevant is this line:

```
// I don't quite understand this line
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Other than that, there's no sorting. We call `criteria.list()` to get our results.

---

Is it normal ? Did I miss something when understanding the way Hibernate works ? How do I get the result I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Hibernate ORM that's doing the sorting, it's your database. When you use criteria, Hibernate ORM will create the query adding the proper `order by` clause to the SQL.

Depending on the database you are using, there is usually a way to define the collation and specify how strings and characters will be ordered.

For example, [in PostgreSQL you can define it when you create the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html):

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    a text COLLATE "de_DE",
    b text COLLATE "es_ES",
    ...
);
```